# Need Help my code Has Errors

Tags: java, date, compiler-errors

Create a class called Date.  Make Date have a static method called getMonthName that takes an integer, and then returns a String representation of the corresponding month's name.  The numbers 1-12 will map to January-December respectively.  If a value outside of 1-12 is passed, return "Invalid month".
View required output. Add two constructors to Date: One that takes an integer month, day, and year Another that takes a String month, and integer day and year. Add a toString method that returns the date is the following format: Month Day, Year

My Code is as follows

```
public class Date
{
private static String[] monName;
private int month, day, year;

public static String getMonthName(int num)
{
    if(num < 1 || num > 12)
    {
        return "invalid month";
    }
    else
    {
        String[] name = {" ", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May"            
    , "June", "July", "August", "September", "October","November",   "December"};
        return name[num];
    }
}     

public static int getMonthNumber(String monthName)
{
    for(int n = 1; n <= 12; n++)
    {
        if (monthName.equalsIgnoreCase(monName[n]))
            return n;
    }
    return -1;
}

public Date(int month, int day, int year)
{
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
    this.year = year;
}     

public Date (String month, int day, int year)
{
    this(day, getMonthNumber(month), year);
}   

public String toString()
{

    String m = month + day + ", " + year;
    return m;
}
}
```

the test code to run my code is

```
import java.util.Random;
public class DateDemo
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println("-- Number Tests --");
    Random r = new Random(0);
    for (int x = 0; x < 50; x++)
    {
        Date d = new Date(Math.abs(r.nextInt() % 12) + 1, //month
                          Math.abs(r.nextInt()) % 28, //day
                          1900 + r.nextInt() % 100); //year
        System.out.println(d);
    }

    System.out.println("-- Month Name Tests --");
    System.out.println(new Date("January", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("February", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("March", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("April", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("May", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("June", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("July", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("August", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("September", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("October", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("November", 1, 1970));
    System.out.println(new Date("December", 1, 1970));

}
}
```

The error that I get is

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException 
>   at Date.getMonthNumber(Date.java:32) 
>   at Date.(Date.java:47)
>   at DateDemo.main(DateDemo.java:19)

and the Month does not display, Only the day and the year. Please Help!!

Comment: Great title to a question... -1

Answer (score 1):

`private static String[] monName;` is never assigned a value, therefore, it is `null`

I "think" you want to take `String[] name = {" ", "January", "February", "March", "April", "May", "June", "July", "August", "September", "October","November",   "December"};` from your `getMonthName` method and assign to to `monName` instead...

```
private static final String[] MONTH_NAMES = String[] name = {
            " ", 
            "January", 
            "February", 
            "March", 
            "April", 
            "May", 
            "June", 
            "July", 
            "August", 
            "September", 
            "October",
            "November",
            "December"};
```

And yes, you'll have to rename `monName` as people will recognise `MONTH_NAMES` as a constants

Comment: THank you but what would I do then with the getMonthName? I am required to have that for the code.

Comment: Ok I changed it to what you said and my getMonthName to                                  else
        {                 
            return Month_Names[num];
        }
    }                                                                                                                           It removed the Error but it is still only showing the day and the year but not the month. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried calling the `getMonthName` method? You should also be validating the parameters within the constructor ;)

Comment: The parameters for `this(day, getMonthNumber(month), year);` are wrong

Comment: The getMonthName method worked ok in the first part of my Homework, then when I had to add the two constructors, one with an int and the other with the string, It stopped working. I know there is something wrong but I cant figure out what it is. Thank you so much for your help, I am new to programming :)

Comment: Look at the requirements for the first constructor `public Date(int month, int day, int year)` and then look at what you are actually giving it `this(day, getMonthNumber(month), year);`

Comment: I have two different constructors, the one that takes the int and the other takes string int int. Im not sure what i should fix. everything I try to change just gives me more errors

Comment: Yes, but you are passing the wrong data to `Date(int month, int day, int year)` when you are calling `Date (String month, int day, int year)`, look at the order of the parameters and the data you are passing...`this(day, getMonthNumber(month), year);` - is this really the correct data

Comment: I cant change it to getMonthName because that function requires an int..Im sorry but im so lost as what to do...I have changed the order and nothing...how do i fix it?

Comment: This, `this(day, getMonthNumber(month), year);` should be `this(getMonthNumber(month), day, year);`!

Comment: I did that, and still only displays numbers no month names. ;(        Like this:                                                                                                                  -- Number Tests --
22, 1849
37, 1952
27, 1828
15, 1839
25, 1843
18, 1978
30, 1982
23, 1936
4, 1946
21, 1815
28, 1930
13, 1839
29, 1898
26, 1864
31, 1846
21, 1877
15, 1902
16, 1865
6, 1908
33, 1984
7, 1907
19, 1983
-- Month Name Tests --
2, 1970
3, 1970
4, 1970
5, 1970
6, 1970
7, 1970
8, 1970

Comment: Okay, when were you going to call `getMonthName`...?

Comment: Im not sure..It worked before I added the constructors. I tried calling getMonthName in the constructors but I always get errors. i tried this(getMonthName(month), day, year); but i didnt work. I tried changing (month) to (num) and that still didnt work. Im not sure where to go now.

Comment: Great Thank you :) now I have months, one last problem is that when it should be returning Invalid Month, It is not. It is displaying month, 0 year...Is there a way to fix this in to string or do I need to do it somewhere else?

Comment: Me, personally, I'd be validating the values passed to the constructor and throwing an `Exception` when they were invalid, but that might be beyond the scope.  It should be doing it now though...

Comment: Seems to work okay for me, prints `invalid month` when I modify the `toString` method to display it (and pass it invalid data)

Comment: Finally, Thank you so much for all your help. I really appreciate it :) :)

Comment: you'll have to rename **constent** as people will recognise **constant**. :D

Comment: @Cataclysm I'm a programming, spelling's not at the top of my list of priorities...apprently, neither's typing :P